# How to make a hexdump line by line with xxd?

Tags: bash, xxd

To create sample file with cat.

```
cat > /tmp/test.txt <<EOF
> X1
> X22
> X333
> X4444
> EOF
```

To check the content in sample file.

```
cat  /tmp/test.txt
X1
X22
X333
X4444
```

To make a hexdump with xxd.

```
xxd   /tmp/test.txt
0000000: 5831 0a58 3232 0a58 3333 330a 5834 3434  X1.X22.X333.X444
0000010: 340a
```

How to make a hexdump line by line with xxd in such way as below:

```
58 31 0a
58 32 32 0a
58 33 33 33 0a
58 34 34 34 34 0a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all I found the `hexdump` tool in combination with `sed` the best solution:

```
hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x "' /tmp/test.txt | sed 's/0a /0a\n/g'
```

Comment: It is  **xargs -I'{}' bash -c 'xxd <<< "${1}"' -- '{}' < /tmp/test.txt**,not **xargs -I'{}' bash -c 'xxd <<< "${1}" -- '{}' < /tmp/test.txt**

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: In your second answer, there is a  **'** lost,it is **"${1}"'** ,not  **"${1}"** .

Comment: Ah I see! :D Damn, that was hard to get. :) ... Anyhow, looks like the xargs approach wasn't a good idea at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ xxd  -ps </tmp/test.txt|sed -e 's/\(..\)/\1 /g' -e 's/0a /0a\n/g'
58 31 0a
58 32 32 0a
58 33 33 33 0a
58 34 34 34 34 0a
```

Comment: Plus one for being the first who came up with this kind of solution! The accept-vote should be yours!

Comment: I have tested with other long files, no enough robustness for long files.

Comment: how long is *long*? I mean size in bytes, number of lines?

Comment: Please download it and save as /home/urls.csv , to test it with **xxd  -ps </home/urls.csv|sed -e 's/\(..\)/\1 /g' -e 's/0a /0a\n/g'**.

Comment: I see, thanks for the test file. Now it is clear! Yeah, the answer is wrong in that case because `xxd -ps` wraps lines at 60 chars.

Answer (score 0):

Please download it and save as /home/urls.csv.

[sample file to test](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9BpilWzmmMCYS1yQUZyZTBsT00)

To test with
**hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02x "' /home/urls.csv | sed 's/0a /0a\n/g'**

[image]

To test with
**xargs -I'{}' bash -c 'xxd <<< "${1}"' -- '{}' < /home/urls.csv**

[image]

To test with
**xargs -I'{}' bash -c 'hd <<< "${1}"' -- '{}' < /home/urls.csv**
[image]

To test with

```
xxd  -ps </home/urls.csv |sed -e 's/\(..\)/\1 /g' -e 's/0a /0a\n/g'
```

It is clear that Ipor Sircer's answer is no enough robustness for long files.

[image]